# Key Verification

Tags: c#, php

Right now I am using this PHP code

```
if($validation != "") {
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

and it works fine ( website.com/validator.php?key=KEYHERE )

I am using this in my C# application

```
private string GetResponse()
    {
        string data = "";

        try
        {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("website.com/validator.php?key=" + textBox1.Text);
            request.Timeout = 30000;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            data = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
            response.Close();
        }
        catch (InvalidCastException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
        return data;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (GetResponse() == "true")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Works");
        }
    }
```

Okay so everything works perfect, only problem is if you go into your browser and go to the website you can check if keys are working or not by going to the site and it will display the true or false (echo from php).

How could I make it so in the PHP code it does not display any text (no echo) so possibly use return TRUE or FALSE? And have the application still get the correct response

Comment: In PHP, put "true"/"false" in the returned URL and test response.ResponseUri in your c# code.

Comment: You can add your notice in http response header,It can not be shown in browse

Comment: @Graffito thank you but can you please show me an exmaple. I an new to both C# and PHP

Comment: On PHP side, you have to send a page with an URL like "website.com?validation=TRUE". But, I cannot help on PHP aspects. On C#, just test the string given by response.ResponseUri after GetResponse(). **SkyFang** proposal is also a good solution.

Comment: @SkyFang how would I go about doing that? Again sorry but I am new :/

Comment: I just know how to do it in C# like `Response.AddHeader("ValidateResult", "True");` ,so sorry

Comment: @SkyFang no big deal that helps :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why no use POST method for web service in php ?